# hadoop wordcount Unsuppored Major.Minor version 51.0 ERROR

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I created a jar file for wordcount in Hadoop 1.1.1 while running world count its giving me following error:

```
hduseros@MT2012018:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar playground/wordcount.jar org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount /user/input/playground /user/output1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/examples/WordCount : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

Comment: try to check java version. if you use java 1.7 try use java 1.6.

Comment: Which Hadoop libraries are you compiling it against?

Comment: I have configured java-6-openjdk in hadoop-env.sh and I am using Hadoop version 1.1.1.

Answer (score 8):

This error comes when your hadoop system is running lower Java version than the one used to compile your MapReduce code.

Check java versions of your hadoop system and system you used to compile your code with "*java -version*".

Comment: java version was the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of jdk mismatch on the machine which you are compiling and the machine on which you are running the jar. Match both the versions of jdk.